# Angular directive not capturing values in local scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following html.

```
<h2>{{ profile.first_name }} {{ profile.last_name }}</h2>
<p>{{ profile.organisation_name }}</p>
<p>{{ profile.email }}</p>
<p>{{ profile.phone }}</p>

<div class="row marketing">
    <transform xml="{{ profile.profiles.profile }}" xslt="LawyerProfile.xslt"/>
</div>
```

I have an angular service that populates profile object. I have some xml data in {{ profile.profiles.profile }} that I want to transform using a directive.

So I pass in the data and xslt file to apply transform from.

my directive looks like this

```
'use strict';

clientApp.directive("transform", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E", 
    scope: {
        xml: "@",
        xslt: "@"
    },
    replace: true, 
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element) {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(scope.xml);
        console.log(scope.xslt);            
    }
};
});
```

When I inspect the scope object, it have xml data as string in scope.xml but when I console.log it, its not there.

console.log(scope.xslt);  works just fine.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

---

UPDATED:

profileController.js

```
'use strict';

clientApp
.controller('profileController', function($scope, $routeParams, profileService) {
    profileService.getProfile($routeParams.id, $routeParams.publication)
        .then(function(profile) {                
                $scope.profile = profile;
        });
});
```

profileService.js

```
'use strict';

clientApp.factory('profileService', function($http, $q) {
return {
    getProfile: function(id, publication) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var url = 'http://192.168.7.37:3000/lawyer/' + id + '/' + publication;
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: url })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(scope.xml)`?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Chrome/Chromium display the most recent state of an object in the console. I found it to not play nice with angular sometimes, so if I log an object and edit it afterwards it can show up empty. I never had said problem with Firefox's Firebug console.

Comment: @YeLiu scope.xml is blank. using angular $resource service for ajax calls.Using chrome, even alert shows an empty dialogbox.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `xml` is bound to an interpolated value, which is from the `$resource` service, therefore it's a good idea to use `$timeout` to let angular's digest cycle finish before you do anything else.

You can try something like this:

```
.directive("transform", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function (scope, element) {
            ...
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(scope.xml);
            }, 0);          
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: that works, thanks. Is there a reason console.log(scope.xslt);  works without using $timeout service?

Comment: This kind of works but I am not happy with this approach, various browsers behave differently. I have changed the service from $resource to $http and binding $scope.profile in controller in .then still directive isn't working.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar It doesn't matter you use `$resource` or `$http`, the problem here is *when the linking function is executing, `scope.profile` is undefined*, and it will have value after http promise has been resolved, that will happen when the digest cycle finishes, so you need `$timeout` to delay your `console.log` call.